# How to deal with nested results in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I want to read data from two associated tables in not nested format using sequelize.

Using this line of code:

```
const operator = await operatorService.findOne({ where: { id: id }, include: { model: models.Account, attributes: ["email"] }, raw: true });
```

I'm able to get something like this:

```
operator {
    Account.email: "adaclark@terrago.com",
    city: "Rockhill",
    firstName: "Livingston",
}
```

What i want is something like that:

```
operator {
    email: "adaclark@terrago.com",
    city: "Rockhill",
    firstName: "Livingston",
}
```

I know it can do this in different way by getting model first, then getting associated model, finally creating object from both of them but i really need to know if it is possible to do in just one function.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use extended syntax in `attributes` on the root level and empty `attributes` in `include` option like this:

```js
operatorService.findOne({
  where: { id: id }, 
  attributes: {
    include: [Sequelize.col('Account.email'),'email']
  },
  include: [{
   model: models.Account,
   attributes: [],
  }]
```

Comment: Sequelize throws this error.
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'Account.email' in 'field list'"

sql : "SELECT 'Operator'.'id', 'Operator'.'firstName', 'Operator'.'lastName', 'Operator'.'phone', 'Operator'.'license', 'Operator'.'city', 'Operator'.'operational_range', 'Operator'.'description', 'Account.email' AS 'email' FROM 'Operator' AS 'Operator' LEFT OUTER JOIN 'Account' AS 'Account' ON 'Operator'.'id' = 'Account'.'OperatorId' WHERE 'Operator'.'id' = '7';",

Comment: I don't see why this SQL should generate such error only if `Account` table really doesn't have `email` column. Could you execute this SQL in come DBMS client on the same DB?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I checked that and it throws same error. Also i made sure that `Account` has `email` column. What i have noticed is that generated sql code has: 'Account.email' AS 'email' which should be more like 'Account'.'email' AS 'email'.
PS. i use ' here in comments instead of ` cause this character displays text different so in every sql code i send here ' = `

Comment: Just try `include: [[Sequelize.col('Account.email'),'email']]`

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution. Thank you very much :))

Comment: I corrected my answer

Comment: Following this solution, can it be done for all names of nested columns without writing them down using your syntax?

Comment: Didn't try that at all because of potential conflicts in column names of the main entity and included one. Maybe there is some syntax like `include:[Sequelize.col('Account.*')]` or similar. It's not as common case to do so. It's safer to stick with nested object(s) for each included entity and after getting it all you can map it to whatever structure you want to